# Running parallel builds from jenkins pipeline job triggers and waits for same job on other project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I have this test pipeline code, it runs 2 build on different nodes on `build_servers` as expected.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'myserver' }
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def tests = [:]
                    for (f in [ 'x', 'y' ]) {
                        tests["${f}"] = {
                            node('build_servers') {
                                stage('Clean Workspace') {
                                     echo "cleaning up Ws ${f}"
                                     step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
                                }
                                stage('create Wspace txt file') {
                                        script {
                                            props="Wspace=${workspace}"
                                            dir ( 'wspace') {
                                                    writeFile file: 'params.txt', text: props
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                                stage('Run other job') {
                                    script {
                                        println('calling other project')
                                        props = readProperties file: "wspace/params.txt"
                                           file_params = props.collect {
                                                string(name: it.key, value: it.value)
                                        }
                                        build job: "other_job2", parameters: file_params, wait: true, propagate: true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    parallel tests
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to trigger 2 different builds on `other_job2`, but it submits just one job and both `tests['x'] and tests['y']` waits for the same job to finish, why is that? should it not create 2 different  jobs in `other_job2` project, one for `x` and one for `y`?

in the console output, I see build #5 for both [x] and [y] exactly as shown below:

```
[x] Starting building: TEST » other_job2 #5
[y] Starting building: TEST » other_job2 #5
```

Also, I am printing `${f}` in `echo "cleaning up WS...` line, I expected to see both x and y, but I see only `cleaning up Ws y` printed for both `[x]` and `[y]` as below

```
[x] cleaning up Ws y
    [Pipeline] cleanWs
[x] [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
    [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
    [WS-CLEANUP] done
    [Pipeline] echo
[y] cleaning up Ws y
    [Pipeline] cleanWs
[y] [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
    [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
    [WS-CLEANUP] done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something needs to be different in other_job2 for tests['x'] and tests['y'].

Example(untested),

```
for (f in [ 'x', 'y' ]) { {
    {some code}
    build job: "other_job2", parameters: [file_params, string(name:'dummy', value: "${f}")], wait: true, propagate: true
    // the dummy parameter is for preventing mutation
}
```

More info:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel

Comment: thanks a lot, you pointed me the right link, can you edit your answer by pasting `the dummy parameter is for preventing mutation...` comment line, I added `for (k in [ 'x', 'y' ]) { def f = k` ... and it started working.

Comment: I spent lots of time figuring this, you saved my time, but please add this info too to your answer, so it will be useful for others `def index = i //if we tried to use i below, it would equal 4 in each job execution.` which I see in the link you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin" you need to update plugin to the latest version (above 1.86.0) and enable "Allow several triggers per build" within Job configurations.